# how to load file contain Polish character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to use the character set AL32UTF8 to load my CSV file. But I got the result My string from WROCŁAW become WROCÅAW. any idea?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the code you use to load the data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: Thank you I just add it

Comment: How do you load the file? What is the encoding of the CSV file? How do you select the data? (perhaps the data is actually correct but your display is wrong)